# How to debug error "Cannot read property of null"

Tags: qt, qml

In a big QML project, sometimes I get the following error :

> MyItem.qml:8: TypeError: Cannot read property of null

When I look at the concerned line, it is always in a sub-Item, with a property binding to a parent property like

```
Item
{
    id: myItem

    ASubItem
    {
         id: subItem
         width: parent.width
    }
}
```

So it seems like the parent became null and the inner item is trying to update its property after that.

We sometimes delete the items from C++ because we want to create new ones, it seems to be the cause of the error messages. We also create some items from C++ (using `QQmlComponent`) and set the parent and parent-item to the `QQuickItem` that contains the items, but it seems that I get this error on other items as well.

But I don't understand why an inner item would try to update itself while the parent is null, shouldn't it be deleted at the same time ?
Is there any way to debug this to see when the parent is deleted and when its child-item is trying to update ?

Comment: Are you creating those qml object dynamically which you destroy at runtime? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html

Comment: @talamaki They are created dynamically yes but from C++, I fail to see how I can use what the doc is saying for my use case

Comment: @ymoreau Did you find some solution to this? I'm facing the same problem - when application closing, I get list of warnings about TypeError from childrens of dynamically created QML windows, in which I set some properties like "parent.something..."

Comment: we ended up with a lot of checks to prevent the warnings, since we found them to be useless: `width: parent?parent.width:0;`. Although this pattern evaluates twice the main object. If instead of `parent`, you have `whateverComplexExpression` as the main object, it will evaluate twice the expression, thus reducing the performance.

Answer (score 1):

a workaround that worked for me, however my case is a little bit different since I'm creating the objects dynamically from Javascript not c++ but I'm sure you can figure it out on how to do it from c++.

I passed the QGuiApplication instance to the root QML Context

```
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("KApp",&app);
```

and then made this connection

```
    Connections{ 
    target: KApp;
    onAboutToQuit:{
        dynamicallyCreatedObject.destroy();
    }
}
```

so the point is, you have to destroy the dynamically created QML objects when the `aboutToQuit()` signal is emitted